# inputting character into a int variable

Tags: c++

According to my textbook, "C++ Primer Plus, Sixth Edition", if I input a character into an `int` variable, it is wrong behavior. So the variable doesn't change and the wrong input is stored in the buffer. Also, the `cin` object sets an error flag, and the `cin` method return false.

But, when I write code like the following and input a character into an `int` variable `n`, it becomes 0.

As I learned, it must be the first value which is 9.

Why does it become 0?

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n=9;
    cout << "now the number n  is = " << n << endl;
    cout << "enter the new number : ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "new number n is = " << n << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*Why does it become 0?*" - because C++11 changed the behavior of `operator>>` to set the variable to 0 on failure. Prior to C++11, the variable was left unchanged.

Comment: Ah!! It's because of the version of compiler???

Comment: @CDS Not exactly. It's a different version of the language standard. One and the same compiler can compile a program for different versions of the language standard. But modern compilers will have C++14 or C++17 as default, whereas older versions of the compiler use an older language standard by default.

Comment: I got it!! Thanks for your answer.